# Compile fftw library as a part of another

Tags: unix, fftw

I can install fftw library by using *configure*, *make* and *make install* for unix systems.

For non-unix systems, fftw documentation says that i need to edit a configuration file (config.h) which have 100 options. Then, compile all .c files to create fftw library.

I want to learn that is it available to compile fftw source codes for unix systems as a part of another c/c++ project. For example, i create a c/c++ project named as *test*. When i compile *test* project, it also compile fftw and produce a static *test* library that includes fftw.